# set checkboxes checked based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have these HTML elements:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" value="1100" class="myCars">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" value="0011" class="myCars">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here are my checkboxes:

```
var elem = $('.myCars');
var car = ['car1', 'car2', "car3", "car4"];
var container = '<ul class="cars">';

for (i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    container += '<li>' +
        '<label class="container ' + car[i] + '">' +
        '<input type="checkbox">' +
        '<span class="checkmark"></span>' +
        '</label>' +
        '</li>';

}
container += '</ul>'
elem.closest('div').append(container);
```

After configuring the checkboxes I want to go through all inputs and set checkboxes as checked where input values are 1

I have tried this:

```
$('.myCars').each(function() {
    var arr = $(this).val()
    var array = arr.split('')
    // array values: 
    Array(4)["1", "1", "0", "0"]
    Array(4)["0", "0", "1", "1"]

    $('.myCars').prop('checked', function(index) {
        return +array[index] === 1;
    });
})
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What is your `check[index]`? This array is not  defined.

Comment: @Islam Elshobokshy  my bad,  return +array[index]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible answer to your question is:

```
// select the .myCars elements, and bind the anonymous function
// of the on() method as the event-handler for the 'input'
// event:
$('.myCars').on('input', function() {

  // retrieve the entered value, and then use String.prototype.trim()
  // to remove leading/trailing white-space:
  let enteredValue = $(this).val().trim(),

    // convert that String into an Array, using
    // String.prototype.split('') (as in your own posted code), then
    // use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over every Array value
    // with a call to the Number() function to convert the entered
    // values to Numbers:
    valueArray = enteredValue.split('').map(Number);

  // navigate to the closest ancestor <div> element:
  $(this).closest('div')
    // find the <input type="checkbox"> elements:
    .find('input[type=checkbox]')
    // update the 'checked' property using the anonymous function,
    // here we pass in the index of the current element:
    .prop('checked', function(index) {
      // we return the assessment of whether the array-value at
      // the current index is exactly equal to 1 (if true this
      // checks the check-box, if false it unchecks the box, or
      // leaves it unchecked); this is why we used the call to
      // Array.prototype.map(Number) earlier:
      return valueArray[index] === 1;
  });

// triggering the 'input' event so the checkboxes are updated
// on page load:
}).trigger('input');
```

```js
var elem = $('.myCars');

var car = ['car1', 'car2', "car3", "car4"];
var container = '<ul class="cars">';

for (i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
  container += '<li>' +
    '<label class="container ' + car[i] + '">' +
    '<input type="checkbox">' +
    '<span class="checkmark"></span>' +
    '</label>' +
    '</li>';

}
container += '</ul>'
elem.closest('div').append(container);

$('.myCars').on('input', function() {
  let enteredValue = $(this).val().trim(),
    valueArray = enteredValue.split('').map(Number);
  $(this).closest('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(index) {
    return valueArray[index] === 1;
  });
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="1010" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="0011" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rz5e2Lvs/).

An alternative to the above is the following, using just the plain DOM API. Note that in this approach I've made use of a `<template>` element, rather than creating a string of HTML and also wrapped the entirety of your `<form>` elements in *one* `<form>`:

```
// using let, rather than var, as personal preference in this
// case; using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a
// non-live NodeList of the elements matching the supplied
// CSS selector:
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.myCars'),
  car = ['car1', 'car2', "car3", "car4"],

  // using `document.createElement()` to create the <ul>:
  container = document.createElement('ul');

// retrieving the content of the <template> element, accessed
// via its id (using a CSS selector), and the content property:
template = document.querySelector('#carCheckboxes').content,

  // creating an InputEvent:
  inputEvent = new Event('input'),

  // defining the function to handle updates to the checkboxes,
  // passing in the Event Object (here referred to as 'e'):
  updateCheckmarks = (e) => {

    // e.currentTarget is the element to which the event-listener
    // is bound:
    let source = e.currentTarget,

      // here we retrieve the value of the current element,
      // use String.prototype.trim() to remove the leading/
      // trailing white-space, use String.prototype.split('')
      // to convert the String to an Array of characters, and
      // and finally a call to Array.prototype.map(Number)
      // (as above) to convert the array-entries into numbers:
      value = source.value.trim().split('').map(Number),

      // here we find the check-boxes, navigating to the
      // closest ancestor <div>:
      checkmarks = source.closest('div')
        // and finding the <input type="checkbox"> elements within:
        .querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

    // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over that Array;
    // check: the (user defined name for) the current <input> element,
    // index: the (user defined name for) the index of the current
    // <input> in the Array over which we're iterating:
    checkmarks.forEach(function(check, index) {

      // here we set the checked property to true/false,
      // depending on the following assessment:
      check.checked = value[index] === 1;
    });
  };

// iterating over the car Array, using Array.prototype.forEach():
car.forEach(function(el) {

  // cloning the content template, including descendant elements
  // using Node.cloneNode(true):
  let model = template.cloneNode(true);

  // appending that cloned node to the container:
  container.appendChild(model);
})

// iterating over the elems Array:
elems.forEach(
  // using an Arrow function; 'el' is the (user defined name
  // for) the current element of the Array of elements:
  (el) => {

    // appending a cloned container Node to the closest
    // ancestor <div> element:
    el.closest('div').appendChild(container.cloneNode(true));

    // binding the updateCheckmarks() function as the
    // event-handler for the 'input' event:
    el.addEventListener('input', updateCheckmarks);

    // firing the inputEvent (created earlier) on the
    // the current element, in order to trigger the
    // function on page-load:
    el.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
  });
```

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.myCars'),
  car = ['car1', 'car2', "car3", "car4"],
  container = document.createElement('ul');
template = document.querySelector('#carCheckboxes').content,
  inputEvent = new Event('input'),
  updateCheckmarks = (e) => {
    let source = e.currentTarget,
      value = source.value.trim().split('').map(Number),
      checkmarks = source.closest('div').querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkmarks.forEach(function(check, index) {
      check.checked = value[index] === 1;
    });
  };

car.forEach(function(el) {
  let model = template.cloneNode(true);
  container.appendChild(model);
})

elems.forEach(
  (el) => {
    el.closest('div').appendChild(container.cloneNode(true));
    el.addEventListener('input', updateCheckmarks);
    el.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
  });
```

```html
<template id="carCheckboxes">
  <li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </li>
</template>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="1010" class="myCars">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="0011" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

With regards to your [question, in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115315/set-checkboxes-checked-based-on-user-input/53115730#comment93127434_53115771), to another answer:

> [How] can [I] use `onClick` to change each checkbox value? [Because] when [I] do that the values of checkboxes in all inputs are changing.

This is possible using:

```
// while this code - in my example - runs after the <input>
// elements are created, and appended to the DOM, we're
// binding the event-handler, using the on() method, to
// already-existing elements; so here we select the <form>
// element, and bind the anonymous function of the on()
// method as the 'change' event-handler:
$('form').on('change', function(e) {

  // caching variables:
  let form = $(this),
      valuesInput = form.find('.myCars'),

      // finding the <input type="checkbox"> elements within
      // the <form> element:
      checkboxValues = form.find('input[type=checkbox]')

        // using map() - the jQuery method - to iterate over
        // the collection to form an Array-like Object:
        .map(function(index, el) {

          // here we return 1 (if the current element is checked),
          // or 0 if it is not checked:
          return el.checked ? 1 : 0;
    // using the get() method to convert the Array-like Object
    // into an Array:
    }).get()
    // using join() to convert that array into a String, passing
    // in an empty string ('') to act as the joining characters
    // (if no argument is passed the default is a comma):
    .join('');

  // updating the value of the <input class="myCars"> element:
  valuesInput.val(checkboxValues);

// firing the 'change' event on page-load so that the value of
// the text-input reflects the checked/unchecked state of the
// checkboxes:
}).trigger('change');
```

```js
let elem = $('.myCars'),
    car = ['car1', 'car2', "car3", "car4"],
   container = '<ul class="cars">';

for (i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
  container += '<li>' +
    '<label class="container ' + car[i] + '">' +
    '<input type="checkbox">' +
    '<span class="checkmark"></span>' +
    '</label>' +
    '</li>';

}
container += '</ul>'
elem.closest('div').append(container);

$('.myCars').on('input', function() {
  let enteredValue = $(this).val().trim(),
      valueArray = enteredValue.split('').map(Number);
  $(this).closest('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(index) {
    return valueArray[index] === 1;
  });
}).trigger('input');

$('form').on('change', function(e) {
  let form = $(this),
      valuesInput = form.find('.myCars'),
      checkboxValues = form.find('input[type=checkbox]').map(function(index, el) {
        return el.checked ? 1 : 0;
    }).get().join();
    
  valuesInput.val(checkboxValues);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="0011" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/PR-selectors-3-20180911/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`HTMLTemplateElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement).
  - [`HTMLTemplateElement.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
  - [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- HTML:

  - [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: @ David Thomas thank you very much, I appreciate your helpful answer

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: @ David Thomas how can i set titles for the cars?

Comment: Is that relevant to the question/problem addressed in this answer, or do you feel it would be a new question? If it's relevant to this question then please edit to add details about what the 'title' is, where it confess from and what you expect of it. If it's a new question, or would be potentially complex enough to warrant a new question, then please ask a new question (with a link to this question as context).

Comment: using $('form').on('change', function(e) { is getting all checkboxes values but how can you get values  from a spesefic form? the first or last four checkboxes

Comment: Using the DOM: `e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('input')` or, with jQuery: `$('e.currentTarget').find('input')`, should find the `<input>` elements from the for relevant form.

Comment: i want to use a class insted of  form , In case the checkboxes are not within the form

Answer (score 1):

You could it this way, I followed your logic and didn't change the basic code :

```js
var car = ['car1', 'car2', "car3", "car4"];

$('.myCars').each(function() {
  var arr = $(this).val()
  var array = arr.split('')
  var container = '<ul class="cars">';

  for (i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    var checked = array[i] == 1 ? 'checked' : ''
    container += '<li>' +
      '<label class="container ' + car[i] + '">' +
      '<input type="checkbox"' + checked + ' >' +
      '<span class="checkmark"></span>' +
      '</label>' +
      '</li>';

  }
  container += '</ul>'
  $(this).closest('div').append(container);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="1100" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="text" value="0011" class="myCars">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Basically while going through each input, you create the container while putting `checked` on each field having 1, as your seem to have wanted the logic to be around that :-)

Comment: I am very grateful that you fixed it without changing my basic code :)  thank you very much

Comment: how can i use onClick to change each checkbox value? because when i do that the values of checkboxes in all inputs are changing

Comment: Could you create a fiddle example of your problem?

Comment: $( document ).on( 'click', '.container ', function( e ) {
                        var chk= "";
                        $( this ).closest( '.cars' ).find(':checkbox').each(function() {
                                chk+= this.checked ? "1" : "0";
                                elem.val(chk);
                        });
                } );

Comment: Feel free to ask another question about this problem as the original question has been answered :) Also it's normal for all of them to change, you're specifying it here `elem.val(chk)`, this is basically changing all the inputs with a `myCars` class.