# How to modify a String, in an input, based on checked checkboxes using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Yesterday, as of writing this question, I came across a simple, brief, presentation of Vue via YouTube and — a short time before that — composed [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53115730/82548) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53115315/82548).

In it, the OP required that the string of text, composed of `1` and `0`, be used to generate `<input type="checkbox">` elements and, based upon the value, have those elements be `checked` (for values of `1`) or unchecked (for values of `0`). It occurred to me, following the YouTube video, that this could be generated with Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'div>form',
  data: {
    checkedStates: [
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ],
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div v-for="(state, index) in checkedStates" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" :for=`group${index}States`>Sequence of on/off:</label>
      <input :id=`group${index}States` type="text" :value="state.join('')" class="myCars">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="entry in state">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" :name=`group${index}` :checked="entry === 1">
        </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/we1kn5qr/).

This was — as expected — relatively simple.

However the OP then, in a comment to another answer, asked if it might be possible to update the value of the `<input type="text">` element based on the user interacting with the checkboxes. This is where — and I've had less than 24 hours experience with Vue so far — got stuck.

My initial assumption was that I should use:

```
<input type="checkbox" :name=`group${index}` :checked="entry === 1" @change="state">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'div>form',
  data: {
    checkedStates: [
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ],
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div v-for="(state, index) in checkedStates" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" :for=`group${index}States`>Sequence of on/off:</label>
      <input :id=`group${index}States` type="text" :value="state.join('')" class="myCars">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="entry in state">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" :name=`group${index}` :checked="entry === 1" @change="state">
        </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This certainly created the required change-event handler, but resulted in the error:

```
vue.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: n[r].apply is not a function
  at i (vue.min.js:6)
  at HTMLInputElement.Rr.t._withTask.o._withTask (vue.min.js:6)
```

(Chromium 70.x, Ubuntu 18.04)

The assumption was based on a mistaken (apparently) belief that binding the `state` data to the event-handler would update that data.

Obviously the event-handler is expecting a function. So, I amended my approach to:

```
<input type="checkbox" :name=`group${index}` :checked="entry === 1" @change="updateState()">
```

Along with the updated Vue call:

```
new Vue({
  el: 'div>form',
  data: {
    checkedStates: [
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    updateState(){
      console.log(this.checkedStates);
    }
  },
});
```

This was a verification step, to ensure that the function call was working which is why it basically does nothing except a `console.log()`; at this point I realised that I could access the `checkedStates` Array of Arrays, but I had no idea how to determine which of the nested Arrays should be updated.

Ultimately I got to the point where I used various indices littered throughout the HTML, and in the function call, and ended up with:

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'div>form',
  data: {
    checkedStates: [
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    updateState(i,n) {
      console.log(this.checkedStates[i][n]);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div v-for="(state, stateIndex) in checkedStates" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" :for=`group${stateIndex}States`>Sequence of on/off:</label>
      <input :id=`group${stateIndex}States` type="text" :value="state.join('')" class="myCars">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(entry, entryIndex) in state">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" :name=`group${stateIndex}` :checked="entry === 1" @change="updateState(stateIndex, entryIndex)" v-model="entry">
        </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The `console.log()` line in the `updateState()` method does log the character at the correct index of the correct Array; it does not — predictably, I suppose — update that value to `1` (checked) or `0` (unchecked).

The code has also become, or at least is *becoming*, a hideous mess; which leads me to believe that I'm not looking at the problem properly.

The Vue documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) *seems* to suggest that the use of `v-model="entry"` should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" :name=`group${stateIndex}` :checked="entry === 1" @change="updateState(stateIndex, entryIndex)" v-model="entry">
```

But that's been used above and, while it doesn't seem to generate any error it also doesn't update the `entry` Array; in that it seems updates to that Array would/should be automatically reflected in the value of the `<input>` element.

So, my problem is probably based on flawed assumptions as well as thorough inexperience with Vue.

But, that said, my question is:

How might I use Vue to allow for:

1. The string of text in the `<input>`, sourced from the `checkedStates` Array of the `data` Object to generate and check/uncheck the `<input type="checkbox">` elements, and
2. How can the value of the `<input>` be updated to reflect the user checking/unchecking the created check-box elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is sound and you're going in the right direction here. The only problem as you said is your unfamiliarity with Vue. With some minor modifications you can get this to work ..

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'div>form',
  data: {
    checkedStates: [
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    updateState(state, index, event) {
      this.$set(state, index, event.target.checked ? 1 : 0)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div v-for="(state, index) in checkedStates" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" :for=`group${index}States`>Sequence of on/off:</label>
      <input :id=`group${index}States` type="text" :value="state.join('')" class="myCars">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(entry, entryIndex) in state">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" :name=`group${index}` :checked="entry === 1" @change="updateState(state, entryIndex, $event)">
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4f9jkoey/5/)

Explanation (from comments):

In Vue you can pass the event to your event handler in your template with the [$event keyword](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers). For native DOM events emitted by normal HTML elements this is a regular event object. For [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) this will be the payload emitted with the custom event. Note that if you call your event handler without any arguments the `$event` will automatically be passed as the only argument.

After capturing the emitted value and passing it to your handler you can use it to modify your state array. But [Vue can't detect modifications to an array when you directly access its elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). That's why you need to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) (or its alias [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)) to preserve reactivity

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Given that my problem is a lack of understanding, is there any chance you could explain how/why your answer works? That way I can hopefully learn something more about how Vue itself works. :)

Comment: @David In Vue you can pass the event to your event handler in your template with the [$event keyword](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers). For native DOM events emitted by normal HTML elements this is a regular event object. For [custom events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) this will be the payload emitted with the custom event. Note that if you call your event handler without any arguments the `$event` will automatically be passed as the only argument.

Comment: After capturing the emitted value and passing it to your handler you can use it to modify your `state` array. But [Vue can't detect modifications to an array when you directly access its elements](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). That's why you need to use [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) (or its alias [vm.$set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)) to preserve reactivity.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; I edited your explanatory comments into the answer as comments are considered ‘transitory,’ please feel free to edit for improvements.

Comment: @David Thanks for improving the quality of the answer. Looks good to me :)